# How do I access Ubuntu after installing alongside Windows 10? (non eufi)

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I used Ubuntu on an old Chromebook for about a year and have pretty good experience using it.  I recently got an HP laptop and decided to dual-boot it between windows 10 and ubuntu (homesick, i guess. :P)

Anyway, it all worked fine.  Installation worked and I restarted the computer--only to find no menu asking me which OS to boot into.  It just went straight to Windows 10!

How do I boot into Ubuntu?

Thank you!

Comment: Laptops that come with W10 are typically UEFI these days, so W10 is UEFI -- did you install Ubuntu in UEFI mode?  (Or in legacy mode if W10 is really in legacy mode.)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the OS boot manager used by your computer is not set to grub, but to Windows. To fix this you need to get into the BIOS.

In Windows, hit the Windows key and search up "change advanced startup options". Hit "enter".

When the settings window appears, click "Restart now" below "advanced startup".

When the screen appears, click "Troubleshoot" , then "Advanced options", then "UEFI Firmware settings", then "Restart".

When the screen loads up, click "system setup", "setup", or whatever your computer calls the BIOS.

Next, go to wherever the boot options are, and change the OS boot manager from there, making sure the "ubuntu" device is above the "Windows" device.

Exit saving changes, and when you boot into grub you will see both OSs in the list.

Hope this works.